flutter exoplayer2 issue makes myapp doesnt work
I'm developing Android with flutter, and the video is not playing because of the OMX.Exynos.avc.dec codec issue.
I didn't even expect it because I had just studied development with Flutter, and when I checked it on Google, many people said it was the problem of Flutter itself, so I didn't know...
this is error codes
E/ACodec  (17099): Unable to instantiate codec 'OMX.Exynos.avc.dec' with err 0xfffffff4.
E/ACodec  (17099): signalError(omxError 0xfffffff4, internalError -12)
E/MediaCodec(17099): Codec reported err 0xfffffff4, actionCode 0, while in state 1
W/MediaCodec-JNI(17099): try to release MediaCodec from JMediaCodec::~JMediaCodec()...
W/MediaCodec-JNI(17099): done releasing MediaCodec from JMediaCodec::~JMediaCodec().
W/MediaCodecRenderer(17099): Failed to initialize decoder: OMX.Exynos.avc.dec
W/MediaCodecRenderer(17099):   android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Failed to initialize OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, error 0xfffffff4
W/MediaCodecRenderer(17099):       at android.media.MediaCodec.native_setup(Native Method)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(17099):       at android.media.MediaCodec.<init>(MediaCodec.java:1811)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(17099):       at android.media.MediaCodec.createByCodecName(MediaCodec.java:1792)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter$Factory.createCodec(SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:74)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter$Factory.createAdapter(SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:49)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.createAdapter(DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.java:113)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1099)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1010)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecOrBypass(MediaCodecRenderer.java:537)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1453)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:917)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.readSourceOmittingSampleData(MediaCodecRenderer.java:954)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:769)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1007)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:502)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(17099):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(17099):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
W/MediaCodecRenderer(17099):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099): Video codec error
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.64001E, -1, null, [486, 720, 24.0], [-1, -1])
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1021)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecOrBypass(MediaCodecRenderer.java:537)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1453)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:917)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.readSourceOmittingSampleData(MediaCodecRenderer.java:954)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:769)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1007)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:502)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099):   Caused by: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Failed to initialize OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, error 0xfffffff4
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099):       at android.media.MediaCodec.native_setup(Native Method)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099):       at android.media.MediaCodec.<init>(MediaCodec.java:1811)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099):       at android.media.MediaCodec.createByCodecName(MediaCodec.java:1792)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter$Factory.createCodec(SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:74)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter$Factory.createAdapter(SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:49)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.createAdapter(DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.java:113)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1099)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1010)
E/MediaCodecVideoRenderer(17099):       ... 10 more
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.64001E, -1, null, [486, 720, 24.0], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:578)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.64001E, -1, null, [486, 720, 24.0], [-1, -1])
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1021)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecOrBypass(MediaCodecRenderer.java:537)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1453)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:917)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.readSourceOmittingSampleData(MediaCodecRenderer.java:954)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:769)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1007)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:502)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):       ... 3 more
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):   Caused by: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Failed to initialize OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, error 0xfffffff4
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):       at android.media.MediaCodec.native_setup(Native Method)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):       at android.media.MediaCodec.<init>(MediaCodec.java:1811)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):       at android.media.MediaCodec.createByCodecName(MediaCodec.java:1792)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter$Factory.createCodec(SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:74)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter$Factory.createAdapter(SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:49)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.createAdapter(DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.java:113)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1099)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(17099):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1010)

PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.64001F, -1, null, [960, 540, 30.044773], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES, null, null)
I/flutter (17099): 

